# Limit Controller Action Request to one at a time

Tags: c#, multithreading, controller

I have the below method in my FileController:

```
[HttpPost]
[NoAsyncTimeout]
public ActionResult FileGenerator(FileViewModel model) {
...
_fileGenerator.CreateFile(model.Id,model.location);
...
}
```

The method CreateFile is defined below:

```
public void CreateFile(int residentId, string location){ 
 ...
 var caller = new AsyncMethodCaller(GenerateFilesAsync);
 caller.BeginInvoke(residentId,location, new 
 AsyncCallback(GenerateFilesCallBack));
 ...
}
```

From what I know, AsyncMethodCaller and BeginInvoke is to process the file creation into a different
Thread so that it does not block the interface. The above method is being called by a web application
and several users can make requests to the controller Action FileGenerator - this will process the
file generation concurrently (may be in multiple thread).

I want to implement a mechanism to process the requests on a FIFO basis - i.e if a user accesses the web application
and invokes the function FileGenerator, while this file is being generated - another user from a different PC invokes
the function at the same time, his request should be queued and executed after the first user file is generated.

Is there any mechanism or method in MVC to queue controller Action requests from users?

Comment: there is nothing 'out of the box' so you will need to research a queueing package of some sort

Comment: i developed an app similar but that was a console application. that time i used azure's service bus for the queuing.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the [Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.8) Class in C#. Instead of spawning an new thread for each request I would suggest using a single thread to monitor the queue and call the FileGenerator method to create file. You will also not need to make it async in this case.

So whenever a user access the controller method, it will place the model into queue. The thread which is monitoring the queue will process it whenever it has some models in it.

This is probably a crude way for Queue Management :)

Better way would be to use a standard Queuing Mechanisms MSMQ, but then again depends on the complexity of the application and required scalability.